# jQuery setTimeout - Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script like this :

```
$(document).on('focus.inputmask.data-api', '[data-mask]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    if ($this.data('inputmask')) return
    e.preventDefault()
    $this.inputmask($this.data())
});
```

I want to setTimeout for this function, and this what I tried

```
$(document).on('focus.inputmask.data-api', '[data-mask]', setTimeout(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    if ($this.data('inputmask')) return
    e.preventDefault()
    $this.inputmask($this.data())
}, 10))
```

But I got the error on console looks like this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah clearly `e` will be `undefined` as per your code, since you have passed a `timeout` object in the place of call back function parameter of `.on()` function.

Try,

```
$(document).on('focus.inputmask.data-api', '[data-mask]', function (e) {
  setTimeout(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    if ($this.data('inputmask')) return
    e.preventDefault()
    $this.inputmask($this.data())
  },10);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm sure your solution provided is correct, however I'm still getting same error. I don't know why, but I think the issue is other script, actualy this script is a part of a plugin of jquery, and I want little modify it. I can't put all script on my question because too many lines of script.